# Angular $resource template does not correctly use parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to hook up a `$resource` to my database via a JSON REST API. However, I've come across a very odd problem relating to the URL template argument to `$resource`. I want it to return the object of `http://localhost:5000/api/person/123` when I call `API.get({type: "person", id: 123}, callback);` but for some reason it decides to try to `GET` the URL `http://localhost:5000/api/:type/:id/[Object object]` which obviously fails horribly.

Here is some code that reproduces the error:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

app.factory("API", function($resource) {
    return $resource("http://localhost:5000/api/:type/:id", null)
});

app.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope, API) {
    t = API.get({type: "person", id: "53b29e180ee099757405fb84"}, function(person) {
        console.log(person);
    });
    console.log(t);
};
```

I've tried modifying the default params (i.e. `$resource(url, {type: "@type", id: "@_id"})`) without success. I heard from my colleague that the default params can be null and it should still map the params to the template but it just won't.

I probably did some silly mistake, but I've been pulling my hairs for hours without finding the catch so I'm surrendering the problem to you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently someone had a package called `ng-resource` in bower that was misleadingly similar to the actual package `angular-resource`.

I'm experiencing infinite shame for not investigating that possibility earlier...